# function $T^n(e^{-\pi x^2})\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: schwartz-space

Let $\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ be the Schwartz-space.
Look at the linear operator $T:\mathcal S(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$
$(Tf)(x)=\sqrt{2\pi}xf(x)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}f'(x)$ and define $\phi_0(x)=e^{-\pi x^2}$, $\phi_n(x)=T^n\phi_0$ for alle $n\in \mathbb N$.
Show $\phi_n\neq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
I think I have to show it with induction, but that does not lead to the goal.
Do you have a hint?

Comment: When you say $\phi_n \ne 0$, you mean $\phi_n$ is not the constant function equal to $0$, or do you mean $\phi_n$ has no zeroes? In either case, $T^nf(x) = m_n(x)f(x)$ for some very explicit function $m_n(x)$, so hopefully starting from this observation is helpful for you.

Comment: Is there a derivation missing in the definition of $T$ ? If $T$ is just the multiplication by $x \mapsto cx-c^{-1}$ with $c=\sqrt{2\pi}$, the question is trivial.

Comment: I corrected the definition of $T$

Comment: $f' = ax f$ implies $ f = C e^{ax^2/2}$

Comment: Yes, this means $T(\phi_0)\neq 0$. But why is $T^n(\phi_0)\neq 0$?

Comment: Make a recursion shows that $T^nf = P_nf$, where $P_n$ is a polynomial with leading term $c_nX^n$ (look at the first terms to guess a formula for the coefficient $c_n$).